# Funq.Container.RegisterAutoWire() does not inject class property automatically within ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, autowired, funq

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.34.

Container.RegisterAutoWire() method works, but when I create an instance of the registered class, no autowiring happens unless I manually call `HostContext.Container.AutoWire(this)` in the class constructor.

I've read [the documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) and several entries on stackoverflow. I've tried different overloads of the Register and RegisterAutoWire methods. I have also tried setting the ReuseScope in different ways. No success. No auto-injection of the DbFactory property.

Can anyone tell me if I've missed a step or done something incorrectly? Code snippet below:

```
public class RouteAppHost : AppHostBase
{
  public override void Configure(Container container)
  {
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString,
      SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance));

    container.RegisterAutoWired<MyRepository>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
    ...
  }
}

public class MyRepository : RepositoryBase
{
  public MyRepository()
  {
    //Works if this line is uncommented.
    //HostContext.Container.AutoWire(this);
  }

  public List<MyUnit> All()
  {
    // Db is null as is DbFactory. This throws an exception.
    return Db.Select<MyUnit>();
  }
}

// For reference, from Metadata
public abstract class RepositoryBase : IDisposable, IRepository
{
  protected RepositoryBase();

  public virtual IDbConnection Db { get; }
  public virtual IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

  public virtual void Dispose();
}
```

**Addendum** (1/20/2015): Here is what a service looks like:

```
public class BlackList
{
  public short Key { get; set; }

  [StringLength(15)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public bool Active { get; set; }
}

[Route("/queryBlackList/group/{Key}", "GET")]
[Route("/queryBlackList", "GET")]
public class QueryBlackList : IReturn<List<BlackList>>
{
  public int Key { get; set; }
}

public class BlackListContext
{
  public static List<BlackList> AllRecords()
  {
    using (var repo = new BlackListRepository())
    {
      return repo.All();
    }
  }
}

public class BlackListService : Service 
{    
  public object Get(QueryBlackList request)
  {
    return BlackListContext.AllRecords();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the Service that uses `MyRepository` look like?